# Shopify automatic discount by customer tag

Tags: api, graphql, shopify

I would like to program an app that gives an automatic discount as soon as a customer has stored a certain attribute.

The following app implements this ready, I just don't understand how the whole thing works...:
https://apps.shopify.com/b2b-solution-custom-pricing?locale=de

I am happy about a technical approach

Comment: Is this app supposed to be a public app or a custom solution just for a single store? What Shopify plan do you target?

Comment: It should be a public app and target shopify basic

Comment: I think you are looking for Discount API https://shopify.dev/api/functions/reference

Comment: I think the app works without shopify functions. It seems that a discount is set via javascript. So a discount that is only set after a certain condition. In the checkout the discount is displayed like an automatic one.

Comment: This is not going to work as discount logic should be handled on the backend due to security reasons and fraud prevention.

Comment: okay thanks, do you know how i can read the tags of a customer? So to check if a discount should be set